# How to hide/show view simultaneously while scroll up/down in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

storyboard design hierarchy like this [design hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mztne.png)

here if i scroll-up i need to hide only topView and need to show secondView on top and scroll should perform from the bottom of secondView and if i scroll-down need to show topView as well

code: with this code topView is hiding/showing immediately while scroll up/down.. **but when i scroll-up then topView should hide visibly(simultaneously) with scroll-up**  how to achieve that. please guide.

```
class ThirdVC: UIViewController, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var topView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var topviewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var secondViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var secondViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    
    scrollView.delegate = self
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0{
        topviewHeight.constant = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
        
    }else{
        topviewHeight.constant = 100
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
}
```

o/p:

initial o/p before scroll-up

[initial o/p before scroll-up screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aePT0.png)

after scroll-up: **its hiding immediately, i need it should hide along with scrolling up**

[after scroll-up screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmUbJ.png)

**EDIT:** I need when scrolling secondView top reaches firstView top then firstView has to hide

so how to calculate to achive? is it possible to use secodeView top constarint value changes? then how to calculate? please guide

here attached required o/p screen record

[image: required o/p screen record gif]

Comment: That's because as you scroll, the animation is kicking off several times. What you need to do is `lock` the view from animating once an animation is in progress and open it up once it is completed. If you can show an image of how top view, second view and scroll are laid out on your storyboard (not just the view hierarchy), I might be able to suggest an example.

Comment: @ShawnFrank, I have edited my post with o/p before scroll and after scroll

Comment: @ShawnFrank, the yellowview hides but i need it should hide along with scroll up

Comment: @JsonSwift - it's not quite clear what your goal is... Do you want the Green view to "slide up" and cover the Yellow view? Or, should it "squeeze" the Yellow view? And, when the Green view reaches the top, is it supposed to **stay** there and the red view scrolls under it?

Comment: @DonMag, when i scroll-up then yellow view should hide and green view should be on top and scrolling should work under green view...

Comment: @DonMag, if i take detail o/p gif then its not allowing me to upload more then 2 MB.. so the gif o/p is unfinished... but the yellow view hiding process should be simultaniously with scrolling

Comment: @JsonSwift - are your Yellow and Green views "fixed heights"? Or dynamic?

Comment: @DonMag, fixed heights = 100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to `lock` the animation block from firing if it is already in progress.

The simplest way to do this is using a `bool` to keep track of the status of the animation

First, use some variables to help you keep track of the animation and top view's status

```
// Persist the top view height constraint
var topViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

// Original height of the top view
var viewHeight: CGFloat = 100

// Keep track of the
private var isAnimationInProgress = false
```

Then use these variables when performing the animation

```
extension ScrollViewAnimateVC: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        
        // Check if the animation is locked or not
        if !isAnimationInProgress {
            
            guard let topViewHeightConstraint = topViewHeightConstraint
            else { return }
            
            // Check if an animation is required
            if scrollView.contentOffset.y > .zero &&
                topViewHeightConstraint.constant > .zero {
                
                topViewHeightConstraint.constant = .zero
                animateTopViewHeight()
            }
            else if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= .zero
                        && topViewHeightConstraint.constant <= .zero {
                
                topViewHeightConstraint.constant = viewHeight
                animateTopViewHeight()
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Animate the top view
    private func animateTopViewHeight() {
        
        // Lock the animation functionality
        isAnimationInProgress = true
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            
        } completion: { [weak self] (_) in
            
            // Unlock the animation functionality
            self?.isAnimationInProgress = false
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you something smoother like this

[image: Animate UIView height autolayout to show hide with UIScrollView swift iOS UIView animation block]

**Update based on OPs comments**

`i am trying to use 2nd view(greenview) top constraint value to change according to scroll-up and down... but here i am unable to calculate correct values to hide and show`

If you want to do that, you don't really need the animation block, you can just keep reducing the top views height till it becomes 0.

Add these

```
// Stores the original offset of the scroll view
var previousOffset: CGPoint?

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    previousOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
}
```

Then update the `scrollViewDidScroll`

```
extension ScrollViewAnimateVC: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        
        guard let topViewHeightConstraint = topViewHeightConstraint
        else { return }
        
        let currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
        
        if let startOffset = previousOffset {
            
            // Get the distance scrolled
            let delta = abs((startOffset.y - currentOffset.y))
            
            if currentOffset.y > startOffset.y,
               currentOffset.y > .zero {
                // Scrolling down
                
                // Set the new height based on the amount scrolled
                var newHeight = topViewHeightConstraint.constant - delta
                
                // Make sure we do not go below 0
                if newHeight < .zero {
                    newHeight = .zero
                }
                
                topViewHeightConstraint.constant
                    = newHeight
                
            }
            else if currentOffset.y < startOffset.y,
                    currentOffset.y <= viewHeight {
                // Scrolling up
                
                var newHeight = topViewHeightConstraint.constant + delta
                
                // Make sure we do not go above the max height
                if newHeight > viewHeight {
                    newHeight = viewHeight
                }
                
                topViewHeightConstraint.constant
                    = newHeight
            }
            
            // Update the previous offset
            previousOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
            
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

That will give you something like this:

[image: UIScrollView change height of view on scroll swift iOS]

Comment: here only animation status changed... but i dont need like this

Comment: I have edited my post with required out put screen record gif.. so could you guide like that

Comment: i am trying to use 2nd view(greenview) top constraint value to change according to scroll-up and down... but here i am unable to calculate correct values to hide and show

Comment: here you are taking care of animation but thats not the issue.. could you update your according to my question edited screen o/p

Comment: @JsonSwift - please see my updated answer

Comment: @JsonSwift - based on your updated gif, it doesn't seem like you need to change anything of the green view which does not have its height changed. It just seems like you need the yellow view's height to go to 0 to give the effect you desire which is collapsing / hiding the top / yellow view.

Comment: its not hiding and showing smoothely.. every time

Comment: could you take a look at this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71733055/unable-to-convert-json-classic-swift-dictionary-methods-to-generic-codable-while?noredirect=1#comment126770213_71733055

Comment: i am new to generics concept.. and there is much more code also that all code i cant add in the post.. so i have linked only this question related code in github.. if there is chance and if you got some time.. please look into it.. and please post an answer..here is the code link: https://github.com/SwiftSamples/GenericCodableTestcCodableTest

Comment: @JsonSwift - I will try to have a look tomorrow evening if I have some time as I am a bit busy till then. Did you try the answers from Larme and Vadian on your post ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't really need to **hide** the yellow view - you only need to cover it with the green view...

This can be done with constraints only -- no need for any `scrollViewDidScroll` code.

What we'll do is constrain the yellow view to the scroll view's **Frame Layout Guide** so it doesn't move at all.

Then we'll constrain the green view's Top **greater-than-or-equal** to the **Frame Layout Guide**, and constrain it to the bottom of the yellow view with a less-than-required Priority.

Then we'll constrain the Bottom of the green view to the Top of the red view, so the red view will "push it up / pull it down" when we scroll. Again, though, we'll use a less-than-required Priority so the red view can slide up underneath.

Finally, we'll constrain the red view to the scroll view's **Content Layout Guide** to control the scrollable area. Since the yellow and green views each have a constant height of 100-pts, we'll constrain the Top of the red view 200-pts from the Top of the content guide.

Here's a complete example (no `@IBOutlet` connections needed):

```
class ExampleVC: UIViewController {
    
    let yellowView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        return v
    }()
    let greenView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        return v
    }()
    let redView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        return v
    }()

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // create a vertical stack view
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 16
        
        // let's add some labels to the stack view
        //  so we have something to scroll
        (1...30).forEach { n in
            let v = UILabel()
            v.backgroundColor = .yellow
            v.text = "Label \(n)"
            v.textAlignment = .center
            stack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        
        // add the stack view to the red view
        redView.addSubview(stack)

        // add these views to scroll view in this order
        [yellowView, redView, greenView].forEach { v in
            scrollView.addSubview(v)
        }

        // add scroll view to view
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        // they will all use auto-layout
        [stack, yellowView, redView, greenView, scrollView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        // always respect safe area
        let safeG = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        let contentG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let frameG = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain scroll view to safe area
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.topAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.bottomAnchor),
            
            // we need yellow view to
            //  fill width of scroll view FRAME
            //  height: 100-pts
            //  "stick" to top of scroll view FRAME
            yellowView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.leadingAnchor),
            yellowView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.trailingAnchor),
            yellowView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            yellowView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.topAnchor),

            // we need green view to
            //  fill width of scroll view FRAME
            //  height: 100-pts
            //  start at bottom of yellow view
            //  "stick" to top of scroll view FRAME when scrolled up
            greenView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.leadingAnchor),
            // we'll use a constant of -40 here to leave a "gap" on the right, so it's
            //  easy to see what's happening...
            greenView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.trailingAnchor, constant: -40),
            greenView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            greenView.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: frameG.topAnchor),

            // we need red view to
            //  fill width of scroll view FRAME
            //  dynamic height (determined by its contents - the stack view)
            //  start at bottom of green view
            //  "push / pull" green view when scrolled
            //  go under green view when green view is at top
            // red view will be controlling the scrollable area
            redView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.leadingAnchor),
            redView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.trailingAnchor),
            redView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.bottomAnchor),
            redView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.widthAnchor),
            
            // let's inset the stack view 16-pts on all 4 sides
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redView.topAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redView.bottomAnchor, constant: -16.0),

        ])

        var c: NSLayoutConstraint!
        
        // these constraints need Priority adjustments

        // keep green view above red view, until green view is at top
        c = redView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.bottomAnchor)
        c.priority = .defaultHigh
        c.isActive = true
        
        // since yellow and green view Heights are constant 100-pts each
        c = redView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.topAnchor, constant: 200.0)
        c.isActive = true

    }
    
}
```

Here's how it looks - I set the green view to be 40-pts narrower than the full width to make it easy to see what's happening:

[image]

Now, if you **do** want to actually *hide* the yellow view, instead of just covering it, add this extension:

```
extension ExampleVC: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        yellowView.isHidden = scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 100
    }
}
```

and add this to the view controller:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }
```

We do this in `viewDidAppear` to avoid erroneous frame positioning that occurs if we set the delegate in `viewDidLoad`

---

**Edit**

If you want the yellowView to "fade in/out" as it's being covered / revealed, use this:

```
extension ExampleVC: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // set yellowView alpha to the percentage that it is covered
        yellowView.alpha = (100.0 - min(100.0, scrollView.contentOffset.y)) / 100.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops! still miss understanding.. when you scroll up yellowview immediately hiding.. which i dont want.. here the green view should move from(on top of) yellow view means while scrolling-up greenview need to reach middle of yellowview visabily as well while hiding yellowview

Comment: could you plz update your answer according too

Comment: @JsonSwift - I don't understand... The green view is "sliding up over" the yellow view. Do you want it to be translucent?

Comment: @JsonSwift - it's difficult to show in an animated gif... did you try running that Example code?

Comment: @JsonSwift - do you want the yellow view to "fade out" as it is being covered by the green view?

Comment: yes, and if there is chance please update ur code with storyboard constraints.. you are giving constraints programatically.. so i could't try

Comment: @JsonSwift - see the **Edit** to my answer explaining how to fade the yellow view on scroll. For future reference, try to do a better job of explaining what you want to do. Nowhere in your post or any comments did you say you wanted the yellow view to ***fade***.

Comment: @JsonSwift - This is not a "do it for me" kind of site. I strongly recommend you read through my description of how to do this. Try to set the constraints in Storyboard like they are set in the thoroughly commented code. Much better to **learn** how to do it yourself. That said, I did put up a Storyboard example here: https://github.com/DonMag/ScrollExample22

Comment: i am new to generics concept.. and there is much more code also that all code i cant add in the post.. so i have linked only this question related code in github.. if there is chance and if you got some time.. please look into it.. and please post an answer..here is the code link: https://github.com/SwiftSamples/GenericCodableTest

Comment: if you got time please post answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71733055/unable-to-convert-json-classic-swift-dictionary-methods-to-generic-codable-while?noredirect=1#comment126773744_71733055

Comment: @JsonSwift - did the edit to my answer, and the GitHub example I linked to, solve this question? If so, you should "accept" it... and your question about generics and coddle doesn't seem to have any relation to this one.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this might help.

```
class HideShowTopViewScrollUpDownViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var topYellowViewHeight: CGFloat = 100

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setAllThreeViews()
        setUpTable()
    }
    
    let topYellowview: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return v
    }()
    
    let secondTopGreenView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        return v
    }()
    
    let redScrollView: UITableView = {
        let tbl = UITableView()
        tbl.backgroundColor = .red
        return tbl
    }()


    
    private func setAllThreeViews(){
        view.addSubview(topYellowview)
        view.addSubview(secondTopGreenView)
        view.addSubview(redScrollView)
        
        topYellowview.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.left.right.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
            make.height.equalTo(topYellowViewHeight)
        }
        
        secondTopGreenView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(topYellowview.snp.bottom)
            make.left.right.equalTo(view)
            make.height.equalTo(100)
        }
        
        redScrollView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(secondTopGreenView.snp.bottom)
            make.left.right.bottom.equalTo(view)
        }
    }
    
    private func setUpTable(){
        redScrollView.delegate = self
        redScrollView.dataSource = self
        redScrollView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row+1).   Hi GJ!"
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .semibold)
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50;
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        //Without this if conditions, it will still work.
        //But we should not do the same task again, when it is already satisfies our condition
        
        let minOffsetOfSecondViewTop = topYellowview.frame.origin.y
        let maxOffsetOfSecondViewTop = topYellowview.frame.origin.y+topYellowViewHeight
        
        if((scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 && secondTopGreenView.frame.origin.y > minOffsetOfSecondViewTop) ||
           (scrollView.contentOffset.y < topYellowViewHeight && secondTopGreenView.frame.origin.y < maxOffsetOfSecondViewTop)){
            
            var topOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y > topYellowViewHeight ? topYellowViewHeight : scrollView.contentOffset.y
            topOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 ? 0 : topOffset
            
            topYellowview.alpha = (topYellowViewHeight-topOffset)*(1.4)/topYellowViewHeight

            secondTopGreenView.snp.updateConstraints { make in
                make.top.equalTo(topYellowview.snp.bottom).inset(topOffset)
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are frowned upon on SO. A good answer explains how the answer solves the OP's question. In this case it would be helpful to explain what was wrong with the OP's code and to explain how this code resolves the issue.